# how to handle precise hours when using WIN32 _mktime on date with DST (daylight saving time)?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, crt

Let's say I develop a ticket application that runs on windows. A given ticket has a validity of 3 hours. Now if I want to print a ticket on 28th of March 2020 (GMT+1, Germany) at 11 PM (23:00:00) it should be valid until 2 AM the next morning. (I manipulate my system time for testing)

Problem is, on the 29th DST-change happens: at 2 AM time will be set to 3 AM.

Due to DST the ticket is only valid until 1 AM (so technically only 2 hours), even though the actual time-leap happens later that day.

Here is what I do:

for the current time I use `struct tm myTime;`

```
myTime.tm_mday;       \* = 28 *\
myTime.tm_hour;       \* = 23 *\

struct tm newTime;

newTime.tm_mday = myTime.tm_mday;       \* also done for remaining fields *\
newTime.tm_hour = myTime.tm_hour + 3;   \* = 26 *\
```

no problem so far. On any other day the 26 hours will be converted to the following day 2 AM.

But if I call `time_t result = _mktime64( newTime );` in this specific case, the resulting timestamp (e.g. 1585440205) will have mday = 29 and hour = 1 (when converted)

Is there another option, that calculates the time hour-precise, so that my ticket-validity doesn't lose one hour? (I assume _mktime64 recognizes the DST-change and manipulates all times for the day, no matter if they are before or after the actual time change at 2 AM)

Comment: That's the easy problem.  What do you do about the hour that happens twice?

Comment: C++20 date library might help.

Comment: Perform arithmetic on `time_t` values (seconds since epoch in UTC), not on `struct tm`. To add three hours, just add `3*60*60` seconds. Convert to and from `struct tm` only for input and display.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, sadly, the base time arithmetic in our software is done using tm struct so I had to implement a workaround for now:

before actually applying the 3 hours I check for both 'now' and 'in 3 hours' if any of those is affected by DST, using `struct tm.is_dst`. I then handle adding of hours separately...

(I know it's not beautiful and messy for the code base, but that's what real life progamming is like...)

Comment: Couldn't you simply convert to `time_t`, add 3 hours in seconds, and convert back to `struct tm`?